# hadoop-0.23.4 namenode fails to start

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have recently set up a simple cluster composed of two *CentOS* 6 machines and installed *hadoop-0.23.4* file-system on it. The formatting completes with no error messages and I can start the DataNodes (on the 1 slave machine I have), the ResourceManager (on the master) and the NodeManagers (again on each (1) slaves).

I cannot figure out why is the NameNode not starting up. Upon issuing the command:

```
sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
```

on the master, I get this output

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/logs/hadoop-cira-namenode-op03.out
2012-11-07 17:28:59,596 INFO  namenode.NameNode (StringUtils.java:startupShutdownMessage(597)) - STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = op03/192.168.100.223
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.23.4
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/conf:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-0.23.4-test-sources.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-0.23.4-tests.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-0.23.4-sources.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-0.23.4-test-sources.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-0.23.4-sources.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-0.23.4-tests.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jdiff-1.0.9.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hadoop-annotations-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-0.23.4-tests.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-site-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jdiff-1.0.9.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/clover-3.0.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-2.0.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-0.23.4-sources.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-0.23.4-gridmix.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-0.23.4-tests.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-test-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-test-0.23.4-sources.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-0.23.4.jar:/home/cira/hadoop/hadoop-0.23.4/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-0.23.4.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.23.4/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 1392631; compiled by 'evans' on Mon Oct 22 13:02:13 CDT 2012
************************************************************/
[cira@op03 hadoop-0.23.4]$
```

And no error message (or at least, none that I spotted). The log doesn't contain an error either.

On the master jps returns

```
2234 Jps
1989 ResourceManager
```

while on the slaves i get

```
2234 Jps
2023 NodeManager
1856 DataNode
```

Any clues on where should I look into this? Thank you

Comment: were you able to format the NameNode properly?

Comment: @Tariq thank you for your clue! I did not specify the master hostname in yarn-site.xml. Now that I corrected that everything works ok

Comment: If the issue is already solved, please post an answer and accept it yourself to definitely close the question. :)